# Nuendo 5.53 Unexpected Error

Tags: nuendo, crash, bugs, unexpected-error

I have a session thats comprised of multiple sample rates, bit depths, and a mix of broadcast wave and microsoft .wav files.

Sends to about 6 FX tracks total with most only 1 plug-in, one track has 3 plug-ins. Relatively low processing power used.

Around 5 folders containing the tracks that make up the piece.

When I export audio mixdown, everything operates as normal unless I choose the destination path box. It spins the think-ring and just sits. The task-bar menus work, and you can exit the audio mixdown window and move windows around the edit bay (the arrow still the processing symbol)

Interacting with the session is impossible.

When you hit export within the audio mixdown menu it fails by displaying an "Unexpected Error" ... no more information is given.

I think this is by far the crazies Nuendo problem I have experienced. I have had multiple sessions with this setup and this problem never existed.

Any ideas? Ill be posting on their forums as well.

**:UPDATE:**

I re-named the audio file in the file naming box to something substantially different (one without underscores) and the audio mixdown worked. While solving my issue mostly... this is a really weird bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually never had any problems with version 5.53 yet, other than Altiverb and Waves messing up my exits from the program, but I know from before that Nuendo at least has been very reluctant to handle samplerates not matching the project. Mixing Wave and Broadcast Wave is no problem, actually the same format with added Mata-data though.
The only way to fix it, as far as I see, is to do a total conform of all the files.

Comment: @ChristianvanCaine Ill move my comment to an edit note. apparently nuendo didnt like 2 underscores in the file name... and then never told me why it didnt...

Comment: Aha! Now that you mention it, I do seem to remember something about N4 behaving less than impressive when using certain non alpha-numeric types! Frankly I was pretty surprised that N5 supported different samplerates in the same project at all, last time I tried that was in N2, and that always (at the time) resulted in warped playback...which in a way was useful too, tho I didn't really trust it :-)

Comment: @C3Sound - Sorry, still keeps forgetting to tag my replies :-)